# I am unable to get xpath for walmart homepage dropdown box using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to code in java using selenium webdriver to click on Dropdown list in walmart page. But I am unable to access the li elements.

```
<button class="js-flyout-toggle dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" data-cat-id="0" aria-expanded="false"> All </button>
<div class="js-flyout-modal flyout-modal">
<ul class="block-list">
<li><button class="no-margin font-semibold" type="button" data-cat-id="0" tabindex="-1"> All Departments </button></li>
<li><button class="no-margin font-semibold" type="button" data-cat-id="91083" tabindex="-1"> Auto & Tires </button></li>
<li><button class="no-margin font-semibold" type="button" data-cat-id="5427" tabindex="-1"> Baby </button></li>
```

I wanted to access Baby using selenium webdriver in Java.
Below is my code:

```
driver.get("http://www.walmart.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/header/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div/div[1]/div/button"));
dropdown.click();
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='block-list']/li"));
for ( WebElement we: liElements) { 
    System.out.println(we.getText());           
            }
```

But this gives an error as below:-

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with  Command duration
>   or timeout: 132 milliseconds".

Please help

Comment: Try this: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. Look at official doc http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: thanks will try this

Answer (score 0):

You defined `WebDriverWait` but you don't use it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("dropdown")));
```

Implicit wait will wait for element to **exist** in the DOM. If you want to use explicit wait you need to use [Expected Conditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as well. Only defining `WebDriverWait` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I dont understand why you are using classname as "dropdown", such class name is not present in the code?

Comment: @user3714889 Yes, it is. Look at `<button class="js-flyout-toggle dropdown">` there are two classes: `js-flyout-toggle` and `dropdown`

Comment: thanks i got it now, but the code works fine till:WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/header/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/form/div/div[1]/div/button"));
dropdown.click();. Issue arises from List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='block-list']/li"));
for ( WebElement we: liElements) { 
    System.out.println(we.getText());           
            }

Comment: @user3714889 what is the problem?

Comment: I am not able to access the li tag values

Comment: @user3714889 If you want the text "All Departments" etc its not in the '<li>' tag, its in the child `<button>` tag. Use `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='block-list']/li/button"));`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Please try below xpath :-

```
//div[@class='js-flyout-modal flyout-modal']//ul[@class='block-list']/li
```

Now first try to put thread.sleep if it works then it is problem of wait only

```
Thread.sleep(30000);
```

But then don't use Thread for your script as it's not recommended .. It's just to ensure that script is failing because of time

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

May be other element in walmart page match your xpath `//*[@class='block-list']/li` and that element is not visible.